# Joomla 3.4.1 change variables when change the website language

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

What I want to do is when I change the language from en-GB to nl-NL (my website have 6 languages), I want this variable

```
var aboutus = $("#intro .intro-block .fa-file-text").parent().html();
    $("#intro .intro-block .fa-file-text").parent().html("<a href='/about' class='introimages'>" + aboutus + "</a>");
```

to change to this

```
var aboutus_nl = $("#intro .intro-block .fa-file-text").parent().html();
            $("#intro .intro-block .fa-file-text").parent().html("<a href='/about-nl' class='introimages'>" + aboutus_nl + "</a>");
```

when the website is in nl-NL

Comment: You probably will get better answers on [joomla.se]. The Joomla multilingual system is very powerful but it is also tricky. Most likely you will want to make the "aboutus" string something more like `$name = 'aboutus_' . $language`; and get the current language from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can use `php` like this

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang_tag = $lang->getTag();
```

then assign set js variable to php variable like this

```
var lang = "<?php echo $lang_tag; ?>";
```

after that just set condition.

function `getTag()` wil return you lang tag like this format `en-GB`.